# How to lift inline files/images from an email using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I would like to gather the name, content type and byes of all inline files in an email using Google App Script. Message object's have a `getAttachments()` function in App Script however this only returns an array of Gmail Attachments that are not inline.

When I look at the raw content of the email I can see that the data for an inline image is there but parsing it is difficult and I wanted to check it there was any Google utilities that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a rather fun one to crack, so here goes.

1. Get your email's raw contents with `.getRawContent()`. This contains all the content, included base64 encoded attachments like images.
2. Parse the email content to narrow it down to an `image/gif` attachment type
3. Narrow it down more to the base64 encoded string that is your image
4. Use the `Utilities.base64Decode()` utility to get your Byte array

Here is what I came up with:

**Note**: This will just get the first image, I'm sure you can take this concept and adapt to your own needs.

```
function myFunction() { 
  var emails = GmailApp.getThreadById(myThreadID).getMessages();
  var contents = emails[0].getRawContent();
  var firstImageStart = contents.substring(contents.indexOf('Content-Type: image/gif;'), contents.length); //Finds the image/gif type
  var name = firstImageStart.substring(firstImageStart.indexOf('name=') + 5, firstImageStart.indexOf('\r\n')); //get name from raw data
  var attachmentStringStart = firstImageStart.substring(firstImageStart.indexOf('X-Attachment-Id:'), firstImageStart.length); //Finds where the attachment ID line is
  var startOfBase64 = attachmentStringStart.substring(attachmentStringStart.indexOf('\r\n\r\n') + 4, attachmentStringStart.length); //Finds the end of that line and the start of the base64 encoded attachment
  var base64String = startOfBase64.substring(0, startOfBase64.indexOf('\r\n--')); //Finds the end of the base64 encoded attachment


  var byteArray = Utilities.base64Decode(base64String); //Retrieves a byteArray of the base64 encoded image
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(byteArray, 'image/gif', name.substring(1, name.length - 1)); //Create blob
  var newfile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().addFile(newfile); //Write new file to drive root
}
```

This works, and wrote the image to my drive, which shows as a proper image.

I just followed the pattern the raw content has it's data laid out in, you can view this by clicking the `Show Original` link in gmail on the dropdown beside the reply button.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, sorry I didn't check it sooner. In the end I moved away from App Script and used the Gmail API with a little Node service but this answer is spot on for what I needed.